# Deadlock from select statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, deadlock

I am getting deadlock from 2 select statements. What is the reason for that? And how can I fix this issue?

[image]

```
Deadlocked processes:   11278 
Victim process: 5185
Lock type:  Index/(Key)
```

Both queries are the same

> object: unicas_ux.dbo.Course, lock mode: Exclusive (X), index: NCIDX_Course_TermId
>
> (@P0 bigint)select courses0_.TermId as TermId17_130_1_, courses0_.Id
>   as Id1_45_1_, courses0_.Id as Id1_45_0_, courses0_.ConvertedGrade as
>   Converte2_45_0_......courses0_.VerifiedCredits as Verifie14_45_0_,
>   courses0_.VerifiedDate as Verifie15_45_0_, courses0_.VerifiedGrade as
>   Verifie16_45_0_ from dbo.Course courses0_ where courses0_.TermId=@P0
>   order by courses0_.CreatedDate asc

Comment: What is not clear in this question. my understanding that deadlocks come from (insert, update , delete). my question what i am getting deadlock from 2 select statements?

Comment: See also [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66098/sql-server-deadlock-two-select-exclusive-locks-on-exact-same-index-and-key). Are you using some kind of ORM or framework? Or are these queries you wrote?

Comment: the developer wrote it not me

Comment: A developer aliased the table `dbo.Course` as `courses0_`? Sorry, but I find that challenging to believe. I don't know of many developers who would alias a table so that it takes *more* effort to type...

Comment: i just joined this company a week ago. i had the same concern like you which i am totally agree with. May be they are using any ORM i don't know. but believe it this is query i am getting. by the way i was watching your videos on you tube very interesting

Comment: The ..... in the middle of the query is throwing me a bit also.  It would be helpful if you could get the actual query being sent to SQL.  The parameter would be nice too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand .. i was wrong this query are created by Hibernate not by a developer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Deadlock happens when one query acquires a lock on a object (rows, data pages, extent, tables etc) and other resource tries to access it. Smallest unit in SQL Server is data pages and SQL holds a lock on page while working on it. So, yes it is possible that two select statement can create deadlock.

**Solution**:

1. WITH(NOLOCK) - If your data is fine to be read dirty
2. Use Read committed snapshot or Snapshot isolation
3. Try to keep transaction small and in batches
4. Use [bound connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213063(v=sql.80).aspx) - it will allow two connection to use same transaction & lock

*This answer is based on your question, as your screenshot doesn't contain any information.*

Comment: *"Solution"* and *"`WITH(NOLOCK)`"* should not be married in the same sentence unless it's a negative correlation.

Comment: @ypercube I agree, but I can't deny that this is one of the approach to avoid deadlock. I did used that when I am allowed to do dirty reads.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick definition of a Deadlock

- Query 1 has locked Table 1 and wants access to Table 2
- Query 2 has locked Table 2 and wants access to Table 1

This creates a situation that can never be resolved.  Each query is going to wait until it can get access to the other table until either the query is canceled, the connection killed or the instance shut down.  SQL Server notices this and kills one of them as the `deadlock victim`.  Note that `Table 1` or `Table 2` could be just a portion of the tables or even a portion of the same table.

The solution is to either not run the queries at the same time, make them run faster/hold the locks for less time or modify the queries to not use the other table.

Without the actual queries there is no way to give you more specific advice.

**Edit:** Based on the portion of the query you've given above (note there is a .... in the middle of it that makes me think this isn't the whole query) I'm curious as to what else is going on.  You are asking for an exclusive lock on a select statement.  That's rather unusual without a query hint.  Is there a transaction with additional queries before this one? Can you give us the table/index structure?

Comment: @sebeid Need *both* queries, in a form that one can read, and other details (like what are the isolation level settings, and are these part of a larger transaction, either in T-SQL or defined by the application)? It looks like both queries have tried to take X locks on the index, we can't tell *why* from the screen shot alone.

Comment: Not to mention that the image is very difficult to read from.

Comment: sorry for that .. if you right click and show in another tab it will be clear and include all the information

Comment: @sebeid No, even when enlarged it is still missing almost all of the information I've asked for.

Comment: @KennethFisher .. the ..... are just col. names. this is the whole query not a  part of transaction. we are using isolation level read commited. no query hint .. but this lock is on the index as Aaron mentioned.